# will following code cause resource leak?

Tags: c++

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int i1, int i2): ip1{new int(i1)}{
        try {
            ip2 = new int(i2);
        } catch (std::bad_alloc& ){
            delete ip1;
        }
    }
    ~Base() { delete ip1; delete ip2; }
private:
    int *ip1, *ip2;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(int i1, int i2, int i3): Base(i1, i2), ip3(new int(i3)) {}
    ~Derived() { delete ip3; }
private:
    int *ip3;
};
```

i don't use **try-catch** in Derived constructor. i wanna know if **ip3(new int(i3))** throw an exception, will the memory allocated by ip1 and ip2 be deleted or not?

Comment: i think the base part is already constructed when initializing ip3, so the destructor of base part is invoked automatically when initializing ip3 throw an exception. is it right? if not, how to delete ip1 and ip2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you could have the same thing much easier by just using `unique_ptr` and `make_unique` for all these pointers.